# Calculate one side of a triangle (Law of Cosines) in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, geometry

I need to calculate one side of a triangle.
I have the angles and the width of two sides. After a search I found how to do it but I need to do it with javascript or jquery.

Here is how to calculate [Law of Cosines](http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/geometry-plane/triangle-theorems.php#law_of_cosines)

Comment: Well...stay cool @T.J.Crowder Sorry if I'm not as good as you! I failed ... ok? Can I?

Comment: @RobW i did not try anything...i do a lot in programing, but not much when it comes to mathematics.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder question edited.

Comment: @AresAvatar and all that vote down thank you for your down votes now i can't ask more questions...i don't understand why you think this question will not help future visitors! I tryed to find the answer to my problem and couldn't find any, so here it is. If someone have the same problem in the future, here is the answer. The knowledge is so vast that no one knows everything and sometimes it's the little things we do not know, that make all the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sine rule:
http://media.tiscali.co.uk/images/feeds/hutchinson/ency/c02395.jpg

If you have side a and angle A, and you want to work out the length of side b and you have angle b, the formula would be

```
b = sin B * (a/sinA)
```

In Javascript this can be done by

```
var B = 45; //size of angle B
var a = 5;  //length of side a
var A = 45; //size of angle A
var calculateLength = Math.sin(B/180*Math.PI) * (a/Math.sin(A/180*Math.PI));
```

Here is a live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/xsGtx/2/)

Comment: var a = 2;
var B = 45;
var A = 45;
var b = Math.sin(B) * (a/Math.sin(A));
alert(b);

Comment: In JavaScript the angles in the trigonometric functions have to be specified in radians, not in degrees.

Comment: I'm almost the same ... this part of mathematics is definitely not my forte!
Ok, the problem appeared because I need to rotate an image. Of course when an image is rotated, it occupies more space in height and width ... If I've got the angle and distance to the center, so I got the angle and the length of two sides ... need to calculate the third side. So imagine 20º 100cm and 100cm.

Comment: @jacktheripper i tryed your solution but the result is not the same as the one i get here [link](http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/geometry-plane/triangle-theorems.php). I calculate with one angle of 100 other of 80 and one side with 100cm...what i'm i doing wrong.

Comment: My one is for an AAS solution: angle-angle-side. You say one angle of 100, one of 80 - that's impossible for a triangle!! The maximum interior angle size is 180.

Comment: Sorry...i should say one angle of 20 degrees other with 80 degrees and one side of 100cm.

Comment: Can you provide a diagram of the triangle (screenshot your result from http://scratch.mit.edu/projects/hamsandwitch678/414392)

Comment: Or even better http://www.visualtrig.com/

Comment: Ok your solution worked...I assign values ​​to the letters the wrong way. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to know, and yeah I thought that was probably the problem!